# Stanford CoreNLP demo and coreference resolution

Tags: stanford-nlp

Consider the below sentences:
Bats are the only mammals that can fly. They are also among the only mammals known to feed on blood.

Input them in the below link

http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process

Coreference output does not show that the word They refers to Bats. Am I missing something basic?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about programming but about using a website.

Comment: Point being stanford parser jar file behaves the in the same way. should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stanford's dcoref module has the pronoun 'they' hardcoded to be animate only, and presumably 'bat' is in the inanimate word list.
The animate restriction is probably justified for the newswire training data, but is not valid for general English.
You can change the animate list here https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/dcoref/Dictionaries.java#L155

Comment: Did not want to modify the source code. Used props.put("dcoref.animate","FULL_PATH_TO_FILE"); Added bat to the file  . Also check the animate.unigrams.txt file in the stanford-corenlp-3.5.0-models.jar file. It worked.